# read() failed Error when opening terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc

I'm getting a weird error when I open my terminal. It happens randomly from what I've tested, so it's hard to find out what's actually going on. The exact error is: `read() failed: Connection reset by peer`
Here's a screenshot for the error: [image: Terminal]

Here's a link to my [.bashrc](https://gist.github.com/fcastilloec/d0fcd68e9570d050b94c892451360afe)
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3.

PS: I have tried disabling powerline from my `.bashrc` and the error is still there. Also, the error goes away when I'm using powerline too. It's just so random

Comment: You could try putting a few lines like `echo $((i++))` into the bashrc, to figure out which area is causing the problem. You could also try starting a shell with `bash -x`, and dig through the output.

Comment: good call, I'll try this and report back